# How to programically change ScaleY RenderTransform of a control in a XAML C# Windows App?

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, visual-studio-2015

I have several instances of the following xaml code. Essentially it's a bunch of grids which show up in a stackpanel in a small (24 pixel tall) state, showing one line of the textblock. When you click on the arrow image (or rather the border around the image as there's transparency in the image) then the grid expands to show all the details within it. I have 15 of these in total:

```
<Grid x:Name="borLecSec1" Style="{StaticResource SearchedSectionGrid}">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtLecSec1" Style="{StaticResource SearchedSectionText}" 
               PointerEntered="SearchSectionEntered" PointerExited="SearchSectionExited" 
               Tapped="SearchSectionTapped"/>

    <Border x:Name="backArrowSection_Lec_1" Style="{StaticResource ExpandSectionButton}" 
            PointerEntered="backArrowSectionEnter" PointerExited="backArrowSectionExit" 
            Tapped="backArrowSectionTapped">

        <Image x:Name="arrowSection_Lec_1" Style="{StaticResource ExpandSectionImage}">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleY="1"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>

    </Border>
</Grid>
```

I haven't figured out how to animate the grids themselves expanding yet as they would have to go from 24 pixels to Auto which I haven't gotten to work. What I have gotten to work is that when clicked, this arrow flips vertically so that it now signifies that another click will cause the grid to collapse down. The storyboard for this animation is this:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="SearchSectionArrowExpand">
    <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" 
                      From="1" To="-1" Duration="00:00:0.15"/>
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Name="SearchSectionArrowCollapse">
    <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" 
                      From="-1" To="1" Duration="00:00:0.15"/>
</Storyboard>
```

As there are many instances of this arrow image control, the target property of the storyboard is changed before every Begin() statement in the C# code behind. The code I have follows. In it, the working_grid and working_image objects correspond to borLecSec1 and arrowSection_Lec_1 respectively in the xaml above.

```
if (working_grid.Height == 24)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("expand");
    working_grid.Height = double.NaN;

    SearchSectionArrowCollapse.Stop();
    SearchSectionArrowExpand.Stop();

    Storyboard.SetTargetName(SearchSectionArrowExpand, working_image_name);
    SearchSectionArrowExpand.Begin();
}
```

The collapse part of the code is very similar in the subsequent else. The Stop() commands are necessary as I get an error if they're not there saying the root storyboard must be stopped before re-targeting. So everything I've said works fine. What doesn't work is that if I expand the first grid, so arrowSection_Lec_1 has a ScaleY of -1, if I then expand the second grid giving arrowSection_Lec_2 a ScaleY of -1 as well, the first image reverts back to having a ScaleY of 1 even though its corresponding grid is still expanded.

The solution I thought up is to have the storyboard Completed event set the ScaleY of the appropriate arrow explicitly so that it would maintain this position even if the storyboard is run again for a different arrow. I can't figure out how to reference this property in C#.

So for clarity, my question is how would I set the ScaleY transform of arrowSection_Lec_1 to -1 from the code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to access the Scale from the codebehind:

```
var transform = (CompositeTransform)arrowSection_Lec_1.RenderTransform;
transform.ScaleY = -1;
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.